# Cancel WebClient DownloadTask Async

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, webclient, cancellation

I have a WebClient which I use to download a file.
This is my code, in which I have a ProgressDialog and a WebClient to download:

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
                dialog.SetProgressStyle(Android.App.ProgressDialogStyle.Horizontal);
                dialog.SetCancelable(true);
                dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

                dialog.Show();// showing a dialog

                string url = "myurl";

                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += WebClient_DownloadProgressChanged;
                dialog.CancelEvent += (s, e) =>
                {
                    webClient.CancelAsync();
       //----------------------- Crashes Here
                };

                try
                {
                    bytes = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException)
                {
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception a)
                {
                    return;
                }
```

How do I cancel the download in the middle?

```
webClient.CancelAsync();
```

throws an exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Comment: What exception do you get, and what's the stack trace?

Comment: @StephenCleary "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Please post [enough code to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @StephenCleary edited with full stack trace.

Comment: Nullreference means you call a method / property of an object which is null, can we see your code ? the full code from where it crashes

Comment: @JordyDieltjens Edited with code

Comment: Have you tried to use a private variable for webClient or better a private locked singleton ?

Comment: @Jimbot Sorry, but I don't understand what that means exactly.

Comment: where do you call all this code? In button handler or somewhere else?

Comment: I don't see in ProgressDialog the event called CancelEvent

Comment: There is a good chance a private property at the class level can solve your problem here. `class myClass { WebClient webClient; //the rest of your code` plus don't forget to remove the definition at the method level.

Comment: @Jimbot Doesn't work. The problem isn't that the WebClient is null, but rather something else.

Comment: @YuriS This code is called in an async function which is called from a click handler. In Xamarin Android there is a CancelEvent for ProgressDialog.

Comment: Ran your code without WebClient_DownloadProgressChanged, I cannot reproduce the crash. It works for me.
May be something wrong inside WebClient_DownloadProgressChanged?Can you post WebClient_DownloadProgressChanged?

Comment: @YuriS I removed the WebClient_DownloadProgressChanged and it still throws an exception.

Comment: 2 things I can suggest. 1. Provide sample project demonstrating the problem and share it 2. If you have teamveiwer I can check this on your PC. If you decide to go option 2 let me know we will go to chat room

Comment: @YuriS I'd like to share my screen with you. Thanks.

Comment: wating for you there: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148353/cancel-webclient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in exception handling code when inner exception was null. To make it work just checking for inner exception using "?"

```
dialog.CancelEvent += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        webClient.CancelAsync();
                    };

                    try
                    {
                        bytes = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
                    }
                    catch (WebException wex)
                    {
                        if (wex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled)
                            return;
                        Toast.MakeText(mContext, wex.Message + "," + wex?.InnerException?.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                        dialog.Progress = 0;
                        return;
                    }
                    catch (TaskCanceledException)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    catch (Exception a)
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(mContext, a.Message + "," + a?.InnerException?.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                        dialog.Progress = 0;
                        return;
                    }
```